# Low current (~100ma) buck voltage converter simple, low cost options (48V to 12V)

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I have 48V AC-DC power supply that I use to drive high power LED drivers. I also want to use the same 48V input to power a 12V fan and Arduino Pro Mini. Fan is rated at 0.25A but I could do without the fan at all if the voltage reduction circuit can be simplified at lower amperage.

I considered linear voltage regulators but with LM317 the efficiency would be below 5%.

I also considered voltage divider but wasn't able to get it to work. With high resistor values the voltage dropped drastically when load was applied. With lower resistor values they would dissipate around 3W with one configuration for example.

Lastly switching power regulators aren't ideal because the cost is quite high for input voltages over 40V such as over 2 euros for a single texas instruments LM25019. Then there's also additional components like inductors that are out of my scope of knowledge...

Are there any other alternatives? Could voltage divider be a suitable solution?, if so how?

Comment: Take a look at the LM5008.  It's good for 100V Vin and 350mA and listed for $1.15USD on TI's website.

Comment: What current are you needing ignoring the fan?

Comment: @JohnD I think that's a unit cost when buying a 1000. Single item is listed as 2.32 euro at mouser.

Comment: @Andyaka will have to confirm exact current required by arduino and all sensors but 200ma is the guideline I am using for now. If there's no fan the voltage can be 5V to 12V. Lower voltages might also make the internal arduino regulator more efficient.

Comment: @DominicM If you only need a few, you can order free samples from TI's website.

Comment: @JohnD that's something to keep in mind but I think switching supply is overkill since my amperage requirements are actually lower than I though.

Comment: @Andyaka I tested the amperage and it seems I overestimated the current draw. The highest I saw was 42mA and that's with 2 blinking led's. 50mA should suffice though 100mA would be nice to have.